# Decorator isn't passing arguments?

Tags: python, sqlite, functional-programming, decorator, pysqlite

I've been working on serialising a n-dimensional array into a 1-dimensional "array" database:

```
from collections import Iterable, Mapping
import sqlite3

def pass_many(vals, some_funct, args=()):
    if not vals:
        return
    if isinstance(vals, Iterable) and not isinstance(vals, (basestring, Mapping)):
        for v in vals:
            pass_many(v, some_funct, args)
    else:
        some_funct(vals, *args)

def counter(func):
    def wrapper(v, *args, **kwargs): # added 'v' arg to no avail
        wrapper.count = wrapper.count + 1
        test_var_args(v, *args, **kwargs)
        #return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.count = 0

    return wrapper

def test_var_args(farg, *args):
    print "formal arg:", farg
    for arg in args:
        print "another arg:", arg

@counter
def insert(val, cursor, table="wordlist", logfile="queries.log"):
    print val, cursor, table, logfile
    if val:
        if isinstance(val, (basestring, Mapping)):
            val = '\"' + val + '\"'
        else: val = str(val)
        query = "insert into tablename values (?);".replace('tablename', table).replace('?', val)
        #if logfile: to_logfile(query + '\n', logfile)
        cursor.execute(query)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = sqlite3.connect('andthensome.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("create table array (word text);")
    pass_many([["foo", "bar"], "pew"], insert, cursor)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.execute("select * from array;") # wrapped select function omitted for brevity
    print "insert() was called", insert.count, "times, and db now contains:\n", cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
```

Output:

```
formal arg: foo
formal arg: bar
formal arg: pew
insert() was called 3 times, and db now contains:
[]
```

Output uncommenting `#return func(*args, **kwargs)`:

```
formal arg: foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
    Line 42, in <module>
        pass_many([["foo", "bar"], "pew"], insert, cursor)
    Line 9, in pass_many
        pass_many(v, some_funct, args)
    Line 9, in pass_many
        pass_many(v, some_funct, args)
    Line 11, in pass_many
        some_funct(vals, *args)
    Line 17, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    TypeError: insert() takes at least 2 arguments (0 given)
```

Expected output (omitting debug function):

```
insert() was called 3 times, and db now contains:
["foo","bar","pew"]
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like the `insert` function decorated with `counter` is being passed arguments correctly.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Is the function call in the decorator commented out for a reason?

Comment: Yes, so that the debugging `test_var_args` function can run all the times `insert` is run to show which args appear when.

Comment: Can you provide a more minimal test case? One that shows the problem using your decorator on a trivial no-op function (`def func(*args, **kwargs): pass`) would be ideal. Also, it would be good to have exact details of what is going wrong - ie, listings of what output you expect and what output you actually get.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working?  What output do you expect and what are you getting?  If you get an error, what is it?

Comment: Updated with current output, output uncommenting `return func(*args, **kwargs)` and expected output.

Comment: Why don't you include the expected output from the debug function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem seems to be that you are using `*args` to expand your `args` argument, but you pass in `cursor` as the value of that argument without wrapping it in a tuple.  Thus your eventual call is `insert("foo", *cursor)`, when you seem to want it to be `insert("foo", cursor)`.  Try doing `pass_many([["foo", "bar"], "pew"], insert, (cursor,))`.

I think what is happening is that when you do this, your `test_var_args` function is consuming the cursor object (which is apparently iterable) and thus leaving no more arguments to be expanded in the subsequent call to the real `insert` function.

Editd after your response:  Don't you actually want to pass `v` to your `func` call?  Your insert function as written takes two arguments, `v` and `cursor`, but you call it with only `cursor`.  Why are you wrapping `insert`?  What is the extra argument supposed to do?  You don't use it in the wrapper, and you don't pass it to the underlying function, so what is its purpose?

Comment: Thanks, gave me a slightly better result: `TypeError: insert() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things: first, in `wrapper()`:

```
def counter(func):
    def wrapper(v, *args, **kwargs): # added 'v' arg to no avail
        wrapper.count = wrapper.count + 1
        test_var_args(v, *args, **kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

You have mapped the first argument to `v`, but you aren't passing it to the real `func`. It'd be better to remove it completely.

Second, and most important:

```
def pass_many(vals, some_funct, args=()):
    if not vals:
        return
    if isinstance(vals, Iterable) and not isinstance(vals, (basestring, Mapping)):
        for v in vals:
            pass_many(v, some_funct, args)
    else:
        some_funct(vals, *args)
```

Notice that when you call `some_funct()`, you're destructuring the `args` parameter. The problem is, when you called `pass_many()`, **you gave it a `cursor` object as the `args` parameter**. This will fail subtly. To fix this, you can either remove the splat operator `*`, or, a better choice, you can wrap the `cursor` object in a tuple when you call `pass_many`, like so:

```
pass_many([["foo", "bar"], "pew"], insert, (cursor,))
```

This will still give an error of "no such table: wordlist", but that's actually because you haven't defined such a table. ('wordlist' is the default argument to `insert()`)

Answer (score 0):

From @BrenBarn 's suggestion I've modified it to:

```
def counter(func):
    def wrapper(v, *args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.count = wrapper.count + 1
        test_var_args(v, *args, **kwargs)
        return func(v, *args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.count = 0

    return wrapper

pass_many([["foo", "bar"], "pew"], insert, [cursor])
```